# Eigenvalues of complex Hessian and real Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, several-complex-variables

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. The complex Hessian is given by
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z_i\partial \bar{z}_j}\right)_{ij}$$
and the real Hessian by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} & \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial y_j}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial y_i} & \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y_i \partial y_j}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Is it true that any (real) eigenvalue of the complex Hessian is an eigenvalue of the real one? If yes why?

Edit: In light of Giuseppe's comments and checking with $f=|z|^2$ this seems to be straight up wrong. What I am really interested in is to show that if the complex Hessian has $n$ negative (or positive) eigenvalues, so does the real Hessian.

EDIT 2.0: I may have something, I think this is correct:
Denote by $L=\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i\partial \bar{z_j}}\right)$ the Levi matrix of a smooth function $f$, by $H(f)$ its Hessian and by $X\in M_{2n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ the matrix
\begin{equation*}
X=\begin{pmatrix}
Id\\
iId
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
We then have
\begin{equation*}
L=\overline{X}^tH(f)X
\end{equation*}
It follows that if $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ verifies $\bar{v}^tLv = \lambda |v|^2$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\overline{(Xv)}^tH(f)(Xv) &=& \bar{v}^tLv \\
                          &=& \lambda |v|^2\\
                          &=& \dfrac{\lambda}{2}|Xv|^2
\end{eqnarray*}
We deduce that if $L$ is negative (positive) then $H(f)$ has $n$ negative (positive) eigenvalues.

Comment: Check if the two matrices are similar. They should be.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro What do you mean by similar, the first is a n*n complex while the second is 2n*2n real

Comment: The first should also be 2n\times 2n. For example, if $f\colon \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ then the matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\parital z\partial \overline z} \\ \ldots&\ldots\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So maybe it is not the proper complex Hessian as you know it, but I really mean the n*n matrix I described

Comment: Oh, I see. So, for $n=1$, your matrix is just $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial \overline z}\end{bmatrix}?$ My previous comments are related to the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial \overline z} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f} {\partial z\partial \overline z} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \overline{z}^2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: With the matrix of my last comment, already for $f(z) =|z|^2$ the real and the complex matrices have different eigenvalues

Comment: You are trying to obtain information about a full matrix (the real Hessian) using only some entries of the complex Hessian. But this is impossible; as a counterexample, take $f(z)=|z|^2$ and $f(z)=-|z|^2$. These functions have the opposite behaviour at $z=0$ but  your “complex Hessian” vanishes for both of them. Your problem is underdetermined.

Comment: That's not right.  The complex hessian of $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ is identically 2, so positive at all points.  The real hessian has two positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @JiriLebl: True, I didn’t write down the computations and that’s what happens! The *diagonal* entries of the real Hessian are zero, when written in the $\partial_z, \partial_{\overline z}$ basis. I thought I could exploit that to give a counterexample, which is wrong, but your answer clarified the issue. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about one dimension.  You can write the real Hessian in terms of the $z$ and the $\bar{z}$ as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \bar{z}^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The real hessian in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ is just a change of variables of the form $T^t X T$, there $X$ is the real hessian in terms of $x$ and $y$ as you give it and $T = \begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\
-i/2&i/2\end{bmatrix}$.  Note that $T^t$ is not quite the inverse of $T$.

Anyway, suppose the real Hessian is $X = \begin{bmatrix}a& c\\ c& b\end{bmatrix}$.  Then the complex Hessian, the upper right (or lower left) corner of the above matrix is $\frac{b+a}{4}$.  If the real Hessian is is positive definite, then $a+b > 0$ (trace of $X$).  If it is negative definite, then $a+b < 0$.  So the complex Hessian "sees" that.  But if the real Hessian has mixed eigenvalues, then the complex Hessian might be positive, negative, or even zero.

More generally (in any dimension) you can prove that if the real Hessian is positive definite then the complex Hessian is also.  It is not necessarily just the existence of positive eigenvalues, it is also how their eigenspaces interact with the complex structure of $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Suppose the real hessian has $k > n$ positive eigenvalues, then the there is a $k$ dimensional real subspace on which the real Hessian is positive definite.  That subspace must contain a $k-n$ dimensional complex subspace, and on that subspace the complex Hessian is positive definite.  That means that the complex Hessian has at least $k-n$ positive eigenvalues.  But it could have more as the above simple example illustrates.

Comment: I think that the matrix you wrote is not the one the OP is interested in; see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822214/eigenvalues-of-complex-hessian-and-real-hessian/3826185#comment7887448_3822214)

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  The OP is asking about the complex Hessian, which is the upper right (or lower left) entry in the real Hessian when written out in the $z$ and $\bar{z}$ variables.  The real Hessian of the OP is the matrix X.

Comment: You are totally right. I read diagonally and thought you were considering the full Hessian in $z, \overline z$. I now understand your comment above, also.

Comment: No worries.  I also added a bit more info on the n dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

**TOO LONG FOR A COMMENT TO THE MAIN QUESTION**.

In the comments to the main question I casually suggested that the Hessian of $f\colon \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, that is,
$$\tag{1}
\begin{bmatrix} \partial^2_{x} f & \partial_x\partial_{y} f \\ 
\partial_{y} \partial_x f & \partial^2_{y} f\end{bmatrix},
$$
is similar to the Hessian in the $\partial_z, \partial_{\overline z}$ basis, which is
$$\tag{2}
\begin{bmatrix} \partial^2_{z} f & \partial_z\partial_{\overline z} f \\ 
\partial_{\overline{z}} \partial_z f & \partial^2_{\overline z} f\end{bmatrix}.$$
This is **wrong** and the function $f(z)=z\overline z = x^2+y^2$ provides an immediate counterexample. The first matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}, $$
while the second is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, $$
and they cannot be similar, since they have different eigenvalues; the first has the double eigenvalue $2$ while the second has the simple eigenvalues $1, -1$. This is in accordance with Jiri’s answer; (1) and (2) are *congruent*, that is, they are related by a change of variable of the form $T^t X T$, but $T$ is not a unitary matrix, so this is not the same as matrix similarity.

A consequence of this fact is that you **cannot** use (2) to determine the convexity of $f$. The function $f(z)=|z|^2$ is manifestly convex, but the matrix (2) has sign-changing eigenvalues, as we just saw. Interesting.